# Как осуществить динамическое добавление ImageView в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, imageview

Есть RecyclerView, в который добавляются элементы (cardView).
CardView может содержать в себе неопределенное количество изображений, поэтому ImageView создается динамически и происходит это в методе addData(), который в свою очередь вызывается из переопределенного метода onBindViewHolder().
Код метода onBindViewHolder():

```
//--Метод onBind--//
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderPost) {
        holder.itemView.setTag(mData.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            }
        });
        addData((ViewHolderPost) holder, mData.get(position));
    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
}
```

Часть метода addData():

```
 //--Добавляет изображения--//
private void addData(PostAdapter.ViewHolderPost holder, Posts post, int countImage) {
    ImageView postImage;
    switch (countImage) {
        case 1:
            postImage = new ImageView(activity);
            postImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            postImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            Picasso.with(activity.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(post.getURLImage(MainActivity.SCREEN_WIDTH, 0))
                    .into(postImage);
            holder.mPostImageLayout.addView(postImage);
    }
}
```

Количество элементов в RecyclerView = 10 (для примера).
При скроллинге списка, начиная с шестого элемента, метод onCreateViewHolder() перестает вызываться, вызывается только onBindViewHolder(), тем самым, изображение, которое загрузилось в шестом элементе добавляется к нулевому, изображение седьмого элемента добавляется к первому (контейнером для ImageView является LinearLayout), и так далее.
В конечном итоге у каждого элемента появляется невообразимое количество изображений (постоянное создание ImageView).
Каким образом можно решить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Есть ли лимит количества изображений для одного элемента `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Ну конкретно данная проблема решается модификацией кода добавления картинок. Надо просто добавить проверку сколько картинок уже добавлено в mPostImageLayout, лишние удалить, недостающие добавить, в оставшиеся загрузить картинки с новых URL. Но вообще у вас получаеся в каждом айтеме свой списко картинок, так что логично было бы туда запихать вложенный `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @xkor, Вы были правы, оформите Ваш комментарий, как ответ, я его отмечу.